# Flex Advanced Data Grid display hierarchical tree using flat data?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, hierarchical-data, advanceddatagrid

Is it possible to build a hierarchical advanced data grid (or similar) without using hierarchical data pre-built?

For example, if I want to show in the advanced data grid (or similar):

Men
  John
  Frank

Women
  Mary
  Susan
  Sally

But my data looks like this (2 fields):

John Men
Mary Women
Frank Men
Susan Women
Sally Women

So basically I want to take flat data, group it by Men/Women and then display a hierarchical advanced data grid by that grouping (or hopefully more than one grouping / tree).

??

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by grouping.  How do you imagine how it's going to show in the datagrid?  You can group columns together, but that's it unless you create a tree of sorts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [GroupingCollection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/GroupingCollection.html). If you are using Flex 4+ you should use [GroupingCollection2](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/GroupingCollection2.html) instead.